Passing keyfile from secrets manager to DBT Core profiles.yml in Cloud Composer 2
I'm wondering what is the easiest way to pass a keyfile from secrets manager to DBT profiles.yml while using dbt-airflow runoperators on Cloud composer 2.
I did all the configurations on cloud composer to configure the secret backend as mentionned on google cloud documentation.
THEN:
First, I've tried using keyfile by passing directly the secrets content, but the format doesn't match as it is expected to be a file path not JSON content directly.
target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      project: "myproject-dev"
      job_execution_timeout_seconds: 10800
      job_retries: 3
      location: US
      method: service-account
      priority: interactive
      dataset: dev
      threads: 20
      type: bigquery
      maximum_bytes_billed: 150000
      keyfile: "{{ env_var('DBT_ENV_SECRET_KEYFILE') }}" 

Then, I've tried using keyfile_json by first saving the secret as a string environment variable and then passing it to profiles.yml. But the format doesn't work.
What is the right and easiest way to do it?
To show more details about my second solution. It consisted of :
1- Getting the secret from secret manager and saving it as an environment variable:
os.environ['DBT_ENV_SECRET_KEYFILE'] = '{{var.value.dbtdev }}'

2- Then, I retrieve the environement variable directly on the profiles.yml:
target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      project: "myproject-dev"
      job_execution_timeout_seconds: 10800
      job_retries: 3
      location: US
      method: service-account-json
      priority: interactive
      dataset: dev
      threads: 20
      type: bigquery
      maximum_bytes_billed: 150000
      keyfile_json: "{{ env_var('DBT_ENV_SECRET_KEYFILE') }}" 

Below the error I get, most probably because the format passed is string not a key : value as described in dbt documentation:
logs for invalid given schema
I also saw the following topic which explains how to transform the json into the correct format for profiles.yml keyfile_json:
How can we store a JSON credential to ENV variable in python?
But is there an easier way and more secure one? Or alternatively is it possible to store in a secure temporary file and use keyfile instead of keyfile_json?
Anyway, what is the best and secure way to pass the keyfile secret from secret manager to profiles.yml?
Note than I'm not using pods, I would like to work on dbt-airflow or cosmos dbt.
Thanks
